# logic and with additions

Tags: logic, arithmetic

the table of logic  and ($ \wedge $) is

```
0 0 0 
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 1 1
```

I can build a "logic and" operation with additions and subtractions?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can do it with addition, subtraction, and logical or.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean truncated subtraction, so that negative results are truncated to zero, that is, $x\dot-y=0$ when $x\leq y$, then since $\neg x=1\dot-x$, it follows that de Morgan's law amounts to $$x\wedge y=1\dot-\Bigl((1\dot-x)+(1\dot- y)\Bigr),$$ which is what you want.

Comment: this is the same of $(x+y)\dot- 1$ ?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then yes you can.  You could have one rule for (0, 0) and one rule for the other cases as follows: If (x, y)=(0, 0), then (x^y)=(x+y).  Otherwise (x^y)=((x+y)-1).

Comment: mmm I think in this solution, but I need the `if` ... I only have additions and subtractions